# How do I create a bootable live usb that uses ext4 opposed to iso-9660, squashfs and casper

Tags: boot, live-usb

I have a 64GB USB disk.

From the ubuntu official ISO images I would like to know how to create a bootable live USB that uses ext4 instead of iso-9660 fs, squashfs, and casper. Preferably with a seperate `/home` partiton.

Preferable I would like the USB to be bootable for both the legacy BIOS process and the EFI boot process.

As far as I know BIOS boot requires a MBR to be created and written and EFI boot requires a EFI partition.

So I imagine the final USB block device should have three partions (`/home` on a partion by itself)

- EFI partition
- ext4 partition (for `/`)
- ext4 partition (for `/home`)

So how can I create such a live USB from the downloadable ISO images?

Answer (score 3):

**Full Install to USB - BIOS/UEFI**

**Mkusb** makes a great base for a USB drive able to boot from both BIOS and UEFI, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb :

- Use **mkusb** to make a Live system on the Installer USB, (2GB or larger).
- Use **mkusb** to make a Persistent system on the Target USB, (8GB or larger), using default settings with up to 25GB persistence, (remaining NTFS partition is used as Windows accessible data partition).

[image]

- As soon as mkusb finishes, open GParted and delete sdx4, the ISO9660 partition and expand sdx5 into the recovered space, sdx being the device name of the Target drive.
- Create a extra ext4 partition sdx6 for /home if desired.

[image]

- Unplug or remove HDD before proceeding further, (optional but recommended, highly recommended if it is running in UEFI mode).
- Boot Installer drive, select Try.
- Insert Target drive

Start Install Ubuntu...

- Select "Something else".
- Select sdx5, (on the target drive), and click Change.

[image]

- Select Use as: ext4, Format and Mount point: /.

Don't touch any other partitions (unless adding a /home partition to sdx6).

- Select sdx5 as **Device for boot loader installation**.
- Complete installation.
- Boot the target drive and run sudo update-grub to add all drives to boot menu.
- Copy grub.cfg from sdx5/boot/grub and paste to sdx3/boot/grub, overwriting the existing grub.cfg file.
- Do not install any propriety drivers, (ie Nvidia), on pre-18.04 installs.