# Ubuntu 18.04.3 UEFI and BIOS

Tags: uefi

I have Ubuntu 18.04.3 installed on a USB stick. Starts on UEFI Laptop. The question is how to boot the computer from the BIOS on such a pendrive? There is a possibility?

Comment: What is your real goal?

Comment: can I run the system on a laptop on which I have UEFI and a desktop computer with a BIOS?

Comment: Your computer has either BIOS or UEFI. UEFI can emulate BIOS. Generally speaking you can boot either way.

Comment: How to boot the computer from the BIOS? do I need to install something on a pendrive?

Comment: I think the easiest way is to install Ubuntu on a pen drive using CSM (BIOS) mode.

Comment: OK, thank you very much. And how do I already have UEFI installations not to reinstall the system?

Comment: It is much easier to re-install. But you can search the site for how to switch from UEFI to BIOS. But it is much more complex.

Comment: do you have any info on how to change from Uefi to bios? Grub configuration won't help?

Comment: Is this a full install on flash drive or the installer which has live mode? Some of the tools that create the installer may make it BIOS or may make it UEFI. But ISO is configured and normally can be booted in either boot mode. If full install you normally only boot in one mode or other as they eventually get out of sync and one mode stops working. If full install Boot-Repair often easiest way to convert. It really is just uninstalling the UEFI version of grub & instlaling the BIOS version of grub.

Comment: [Convert from EFI to BIOS boot mode](https://askubuntu.com/q/360543/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert from EFI to BIOS boot mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360543/convert-from-efi-to-bios-boot-mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically three different configurations of Ubuntu systems in USB drives.

- Live-only system for testing, installing, repairing
- Persistent live system for a portable system, where you can install programs and save data
- Installed system, installed like into an internal drive, but into a USB drive

### Live-only system

- Easiest to create, simply clone from the iso file to the USB drive
- Good enough in most cases
- Boots both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode

### Persistent live system

- Fairly easy to create, when you use a suitable tool
- Very good portability between computers
- You can install application programs, tweak the system and save files
- You cannot upgrade the linux kernel and its device drivers
- Sensitive to corruption (you need frequent backups)
- Boots both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode

### Installed system

An installed system, installed like into an internal drive, but into a USB drive.

- Fairly easy to create, if you want to run in either UEFI or BIOS mode
- Possible but more difficult to make it boot both in UEFI and BIOS mode
- Fairly good portability between computers
- You can install and tweak 'everything' just like with a system installed into an internal drive (only limited by the size of the drive)
- Fairly robust to corruption, but a USB pendrive's hardware is sensitive to corruption (you need frequent backups)

### Details and links

I think that you want an installed system, that can boot both in UEFI and BIOS mode, and in that case the following links may be helpful,

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS

[How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312)

[Installed system booting via mkusb's boot system by C.S.Cameron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107281/how-do-i-create-a-bootable-live-usb-that-uses-ext4-opposed-to-iso-9660-squashfs/1107334#1107334)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the **boot order** from your HDD or SSD to Pendrive by pressing **f9** before something loads up.

**Insert ubuntu installed pen-drive > Press Power button > start pressing f9(Function key) > move up/down by pressing ↑/↓ choose pendive > press enter**.

Try to boot up once with changing boot order if it goes correctly you can also change boot order permanently in BIOS under boot option.

If this doesn't work kindly let me know.