# Start a full Ubuntu install from 128GB USB stick on MacOSX laptop with EFI

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, live-usb

I hope you can help me with an answer.

I run Mac OSX 10.9.5 on my late macbook and want to switch to Ubuntu - once I am more familiar with it.

I downloaded a live USB image of Kubuntu19.10 and created an iso on one USB stick.

I put in another USB stick and installed the Kubuntu 19.10 on that non-iso stick according to the instructions I found using ubuntu-prepare -installation. 
I used the KDE partition manager.
First I created a 500mb Fat32 partition, then a 116 GB ext4 partition and a 4 GB swap partition.

I then formatted the fat32, a 48 GB and a68 GB home partition.

Then I was hoping to boot into the Kubuntu system using the Mac option -key on bootup - which didn't happen at all.

I then installed the rEFInd utility and now at least I am able to boot my Mac OSX again.

But no chance to boot into Kubuntu - although two icons show up. Maybe a USB stick can't be configured to work as a second hard disk?

Comment: You should be able to use the USB as a disk.  Check the USB's EFI partition, it's probably empty.  See bug 1396379.  Copy the hard disk's EFI  files  to the stick's EFI.

Comment: Thank you - but how do I do that?

I can't check anything on the USB stick using Mac OSX...

Comment: @Mona https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/partition-a-physical-disk-dskutl14027/mac shows how to use the Disk Utility; or, choose a different tool, such as one of these https://www.igeeksblog.com/best-partition-manager-for-mac/

Answer (score 3):

### Live, persistent live and installed systems in USB drives

- It *can* work to install an Ubuntu based system like into an internal drive but into a USB drive, and I have done it many times, but only with PC computers. I have no Mac computer, so I don't know the details how to do that.
- **You can make a live drive work in a Mac computer**, and you should also be able to make a persistent live drive work.

  - Try with `mkusb` installed temporarily into your current Kubuntu live drive), or
  - try with a simpler method that works with Kubuntu 19.10 using `mkusb-minp`.

### Suggested method for installed system to work from USB in a Mac

It should also be possible to make an installed system in a USB drive like you tried to do it, maybe with some minor modification. But it is more likely to work with the boot system of `mkusb` to make an installed Kubuntu system work from USB as described by C.S.Cameron. So I suggest to

- boot into the Kubuntu live drive
- install `mkusb` and have the iso file available (in a mounted partition)
- use `mkusb` to create a persistent live drive in another drive, the 'target USB'
- continue with `gparted` according to the method described by C.S.Cameron in the last link (which is an answer to another question here at AskUbuntu).

### See the following links

- [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)
- [mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)
- [How is it easier to make a persistent live drive with Ubuntu 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10/1181857#1181857)

---

- [Installed system in USB ('standard' method)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312)
- [**Installed system booting via mkusb's boot system by C.S.Cameron**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107281/how-do-i-create-a-bootable-live-usb-that-uses-ext4-opposed-to-iso-9660-squashfs/1107334#1107334)